# PHP not reading command line params

Tags: php, command-line-arguments

I created a small script I use for 'cleaning' sitemap file from certain links. I think I used it before with no problems, but am unable to use it now because of a strange bug - no command line params are read at all.

I'm probably looking at the wrong place, but I googled and all I get is the usage I'm implementing already.

Please check the following code snippet:

```
 if(count($argv) != 4) {
            echo "\n\nUSAGE: php cleanSitemap.php <input file> <output file> <bad str>\n"
                    ."This script parses <input file>, skipping all the sitemap XML elements containing <bad str>,\n"
                    ."writting only 'good' XML elements into sitemap.\n"
                    ."Sample: php cleanSitemap.php sitemap.xml sitemap_clean.xml protect-x\n"
                    ."\n";
            echo "You entered " . count($argv) . " parameters.\n";
            exit();
    }
```

What do you think, where is the problem???

EDIT:
To simplify things, I created test.php with following content:

```
<?php
        echo count($argv) ."\n";
        print_r($argv);
        echo "\n";
?>
```

> -bash-3.2$ /web/cgi-bin/php5 test.php 1 2 3 45
>
> Content-type: text/html
>
> 0

Ok... While writing this, I think I may have come to something: this is php5 client used on Godaddy shared hosting. Maybe it's somehow set not to be used via command line? Or, if used, it's not accepting command line arguments.

Comment: Can you show us what you're entering into the command line?

Comment: Can you please post the result of `print_r($argv);` ?

Comment: How do you call that programm? What does var_dump($argv) tell you?

Comment: What comes before? Did you know that `$argc` contains the same value as `count($argv)` (the number of arguments) ?

Comment: Maybe you can check error log file to see if there is some thing wrong or check PHP.ini config

Comment: Ok.. I edited the question with answer to some of your comments.
@mike,peehaa: please check the edit i inserted to question
@halfdan: used print_r instead. is that ok?
@lekensteyn: $argc isn't very useful, since i get 0 element array
@szamdev: yes, i could, but using godaddy hosting isn't very fond of error logs... maybe i'm doing smt wrong, but i never found ANY error logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohhhhhhhhhhh... Ok, I'm a total noob.

I have just found out that this problem was really related to the use of the incorrect php binary... Namely, the 'right' one could be found in  `/usr/local/php5/bin/php` .

I'm really sorry for this mistake.

Comment: just had the same problem. Your answer helped me out. Thanks!

Comment: Always love to hear that my scre*ups help other people ;)

Comment: Me too... Well, on some doc page of go daddy, it is said to use the other /web/cgi-bin/php version... So thanks for being more useful than go daddy's indications !!

Comment: make sure you don't forget this is a pretty old post my friend :). who knows what they changed!